# Loading packages without exiting the kernel

Tags: packages

I find that I always need to exit the kernel in order to load the changes within a package successfully:

```
Exit[]; (* Execute this in a cell *)

ClearAll["PackageName`*"];

Needs["PackageName`"];
```

Without the `Exit[]` command, changes to the functions inside the package are never loaded, and I continue to get the old outputs for the functions.  Is there a way to force the loading of packages without exiting the kernel and re-running computations, some of which take several minutes?

Comment: Also, `Needs` doesn't re-load if it has been loaded once (as documented). Use `Get` for that.  ``ClearAll["PackageName`*"]`` does not clear ``ClearAll["PackageName`Private`*"]``, which is likely the most critical part.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you.  Between `Get` and clearing the private scope, the problem appears to be solved.

Comment: @Szabolcs although, you have to admit that it is counterintuitive to find that `ClearAll["PackageName`*"]` does not clear `PackageName`Private`*`. I think it should.

Comment: Yes, counterintuitive. But probably also useful.  If there's a `*` before the context mark, then it can descend into any number of sub-contexts. You can thus use ``MyPackage`*`*`` along with ``MyPackage`*``.